# How do I convert a pdf to an image?

Tags: converters

How do I convert a pdf to an image (say a .png or .tiff file)?

Is there a way to do this without purchasing a third-party component?

Comment: If you are looking for a real answer, perhaps you should ask a real question.

Comment: Your question is too vague..  What language are you trying to use?  Have you written any code or looked at anything else?

Comment: Do you mean manually convert a pdf file to an image OR a coded way to convert pdf to images. 

IF second option, please indicate which programming language please.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Imagemagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) you can call these programs from roughly any programing language. And it is available on Unix, Windows, Mac, ...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to manually convert a PDF. Yo have two ways of doing it:

**Online**:

- **PRO**: very very easy.
- **CONTRA**: if your document is somewhat private your are giving it away.

I used last week Neevia and worked perfectly: http://convert.neevia.com/pdfconvert/

**In your machine**

- **PRO**: More Secure.
- **CONTRA**: You need to download a program and have it setup.

Here you can find 3 ways of converting it online and another three from your pc.
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-ways-to-convert-a-pdf-file-to-a-jpg-image/

Answer (score -1):

You can use next solution with `fitz` and `PIL` python libraries

```py
import io
import fitz
from PIL import Image 

def process_pdf(self, io_bytes: io.BytesIO) -> None:
    try:
        pdf = fitz.open(stream=io_bytes, filetype="pdf")
    except fitz.fitz.FileDataError:
        msg = "Broken pdf for file"
        raise RuntimeError(msg)

    for page_num in range(0, pdf.page_count):
        page = pdf.load_page(page_num)
        logging.info("yield page %s/%s", page_num, pdf.page_count)
        dpi = min(int(300 * 1080 / max(page.mediabox_size.x, page.mediabox_size.y)), 300)
        # A4 is ~12 inches, # 300 dpi => 1mm
        pix = page.get_pixmap(dpi=dpi)
        with io.BytesIO() as page_io_bytes:
            page_io_bytes.write(pix.pil_tobytes(format="webp", optimize=True))
            with Image.open(page_io_bytes) as image:
                image.save(f"page_{page_num + 1}.png", "png")
```